# Python: Overload [] to duplicate numpy behavior?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a class:

```
class Data:
  data: np.ndarray
  def __init__(self):
      self.data = np.zeros((10,10))
      self.str2col = { str(i):i for i in range(0,10) }
  def __get_col(self,i):
      """
      @param i: STR or INT
      """
      if isinstance(i,int):
        return i 
      if isinstance(i,str):
        return self.str2col[i]
      raise Exception("Invalid index")
```

Assuming I haven't made any errors, I can index this class as follows:

```
i = '4'
j = 4
obj = Data()
point = obj.data[obj.__get_col(i),obj.__get_col(j)]
```

The question is: how does one, in python, overload the "[]" such that I can write, in full numpy indexing syntax,

```
data = obj[:,:]
data = obj['1',:]
data = obj[:,'2']
```

Comment: `obj[x:y:z]` is equivalent to `obj.__getitem__(slice(x,y,z))`, and note, the commas are just tuples, so something like `obj[x0:y0:z0, x1,y1,z1]` is equivalent to `obj.__getitem__((slice(x0,y0,z0),slice(x1,y1,z1)))`

Comment: The `:` triggers the creation of a `slice` object; `obj[x0:y0:z0, x1,y1,z1]` is equivalent to `obj.__getitem__((slice(x0,y0,z0), x1, y1, z1)`.

Comment: Technically, I think the commas are part of the syntax, not a tuple expression, though the end result is the same (`__getitem__` receiving a tuple). I'm not sure there is any way to observe the difference at the Python level, though.

Comment: The numpy `index_tricks` file has a bunch of classes with custom indexing code.  It may give you ideas.